# Is there a destroy method for FlexSlider

Tags: jquery, dom, flexslider

I am trying to reinitialize FlexSlider with out page refresh when a new gallery listing is called asynchronously.

I would think the routine below would work but it doesn't.  It seems like the first FlexSlider persists even though the new images are successfully loaded.

Is there a way to destroy, then rebuild the gallery?

Thanks

```
function flexInit() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlsContainer: ".paginator",
            manualControls: 'a',
            after: function(slider){
                if(slider.atEnd == true)    {
                    // ??? slider.destroy;
                    galBuild();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function galBuild() {
            $.getJSON("/gallery/next/"+galID, function (data) {
            var results = data.objects;
            var list = $(".flexslider ul.slides");
            var i = 0;
            $.each(results, function () {

                list.append('<li><p>' + results[i].title + '</p><img src="' + results[i].src + '"><p class="flex-caption">' + results[i++].caption + '</p></li>');

            });

            flexInit(); 

            });
    }

    galBuild();
```

Comment: from where "galID" argument passed in galBuild() function?

Comment: Hi Kundan... galID is just a global gallery variable declared earlier on.  Doesn't really have any bearing on reinitializing FlexSlider

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i'm using different approach i.e.

you've started one flexslider:

```
    $('#element).flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      directionNav: true
    });
```

when I want to change slides in previously created slider and restart it, id do following things:

- creating temporaty div:

  ```
  $('#element).before('
      <div id="element_temp" class="flexslider"></div>
  ');
  ```
- delete div with previously created slider

  ```
  $('#element).remove();
  ```
- insert new list of slides into temporary div:

  ```
  var html = `
  <ul class='slides">
  <li><img src="link to image" /></li>
  <li><img src="link to image" /></li>
  <li><img src="link to image" /></li>
  </ul>`;
  $('#element_temp').html(html);
  ```
- start flexslider on temp div

  ```
  $('#element_temp').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: true
  });
  ```
- change div ID from element_temp to element

  ```
  $('#element_temp').attr('id','element');
  ```

and it works with multiple flexliders

Comment: this was very helpful - I didn't need to change the id at the end though it was screwing the up the start point of my slider but I apprecaited the info

Comment: Thank you! It's unfortunate FlexSlider doesn't provide an easy way to 'reset' the slider. This solution seems to be working well though.

Answer (score 2):

Rob i investigated this and find the solution

You need to modify your functions like this

```
function flexInit() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlsContainer: ".paginator",
        manualControls: 'a',
        after: function(slider){
            if(slider.atEnd == true)    {
                slider.addSlide(galBuild());
            }
        }
    });
}


function galBuild() {
   $.getJSON("/gallery/next/"+galID, function (data) {
    var results = data.objects;
    var i = 0;
    $.each(results, function () {
       return ('<li><p>' + results[i].title + '</p><img src="' + results[i].src + '"><p class="flex-caption">' + results[i++].caption + '</p></li>');
    });

   });
}

flexInit();
```

Also you need to do some cosmetic changes in flexSlider.js file in **slider.update** function. right now its not checking the position variable if it comes **undefined**, so you will have to check this as well.

Comment: Kundan... you're definitely taking me down the right road here.  THanks.  When the FlexSlider is called again though, the control area goes wild trying to get setup and I get a stack error

$.flexslider.methods.controlNav.update
$.flexslider.slider.update

I will keep you updated on my progress

Answer (score 2):

The most easy way is to remove the flexscroll from element dataset

```
function flexInit() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlsContainer: ".paginator",
        manualControls: 'a',
        after: function(slider){
            if(slider.atEnd == true)    {
                slider.addSlide(galBuild());
            }
        }
    });
}
//this remove flexslider form element dataset
$('.flexslider').removeData("flexslider");
```

and now you are free to call

```
flexInit();
```

and your flexslider will be recreated.