# Clearing and adding slides / Reinitialising flexslider?

Tags: jquery, gallery, carousel, flexslider

How do I remove all slides from flexslider and add new slides?

Or how to do I destroy and reintialise flexslider?

Basically I want to reset flexslider either way.

```
//Create hotel image array
$('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 0,
    minItems: 4,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel",
    start: function (slider) {
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
});
```

Links to flexslider:

- [http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhPymSpaQrNksPpdCZq5?p=preview)
- https://github.com/woothemes/flexslider

EDIT:

PLUNKR LINK: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhPymSpaQrNksPpdCZq5?p=preview)

I downloaded this version which is supposed to have a destroy method:
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/pull/716

I thought this would be the answer but for some reason my carousel seems to no longer work after loading in a second set as if I didn't reinitialize it again?

Comment: Well at the moment I'm simply calling flexslider everytime the gallery list item refreshes. This is obviously causing unusual results. There doesnt seem to be much documentation on how to actually do this. I'll setup a plunkr soon.

Comment: I've added a plunkr link now, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after digging around it turns out that flexslider now has a destroy method but it required me to use the demo on the github page to get it working. I created a working plunker which adds and removes a flexslider carousel [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/RISs6Hp7DLEEr08DeAw1?p=preview)

Also see here: [LINK](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/pull/716)

Comment: just in case people with similar problems bump into here ... I'm using  FlexSlider v2.3.0 and .flexslider("destroy") doesn't seem to be working anymore. The other solution presented below (by removing and recreating the element) works but I've used a easier solution
    
`//this remove flexslider form element dataset
$('.flexslider').removeData("flexslider");`
    
Reference
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248283/is-there-a-destroy-method-for-flexslider

Answer (score 6):

Step 1 - remove existing slides:

```
var slider = $('.flexslider');
while (slider.data('flexslider').count > 0) 
                    slider.data('flexslider').removeSlide(0);
```

Step 2 - add new slides:

```
slider.data('flexslider').addSlide('<li>Hello world!</li>');
slider.data('flexslider').addSlide('<li>This is awsome</li>');
```

---

UPDATE!

Step 3 - set focus back on the first slide (omitting this step resulted in getting empty slides from time to time)

```
slider.flexslider(0);
```

Comment: This causes mine to no longer loop

Answer (score 0):

You should include a link to flexslider in the OP, it's not one I've used / have access to off the top of my head.  With that said, generally good plugins tend to come with a destroy method.  First thing I would try would be to see if a destroy method is defined on flexslider, like so:

```
$('#slider').flexslider("destroy");
```

EDIT:

Looks like this thread has some good tips / code towards the bottom to try out - https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/78

Comment: Added relevant links. Destroy does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Edited my answer with a link to a flexslider issue in github that may help.

Comment: I have added a plunkr link which uses the "destroy" method. Please take a look. Perhaps finding a way to remove all image slides and adding the other image slides is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to follow this. Basically it initiate 1 slider. Then if you want to reinitiate then remove first slider html/data and all then start adding new and initiate it.

you've started one flexslider:

```
    $('#element').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      directionNav: true
    });
```

when I want to change slides in previously created slider and restart it, id do following things:

- creating temporaty div:

  ```
  $('#element').before('
      <div id="element_temp" class="flexslider"></div>
  ');
  ```
- delete div with previously created slider

  ```
  $('#element').remove();
  ```
- insert new list of slides into temporary div:

  ```
  var html = `
  <ul class='slides">
  <li><img src="link to image" /></li>
  <li><img src="link to image" /></li>
  <li><img src="link to image" /></li>
  </ul>`;
  $('#element_temp').html(html);
  ```
- start flexslider on temp div

  ```
  $('#element_temp').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: true
  });
  ```
- change div ID from element_temp to element

  ```
  $('#element_temp').attr('id','element');
  ```