# Ajax image NOT changing on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

HTML

```
    <div class="new-product">
        <div class="col-md-5 zoom-grid">
            <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                     <li data-thumb="images/<?php echo $productimg1?>">
                        <div id="style_image" class="thumb-image" ><img  src="images/<?php echo $productimg1?>" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" alt="" /> </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-thumb="images/<?php echo $productimg2?>">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have this html where image comes from database using php 
 now I need to change that image with ajax

```
    <script>

function getState(val) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    data: {id: val},
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
        $("#style_code").children().remove();
        $("#style_image").children().remove();
         data.option.forEach(function (item) {
                $("#style_code").append('<option value="' + item.color_name + '">' + item.size + '</option>');

                $('#style_image').append('<img  src="images/'+item.image_name+'" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" alt="" />')
            //$("#style_image").html(data);


            });

    }
    });
    }
</script>
```

check.php

```
        <?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommercedb") or die(mysql_error());


if(!empty($_POST["id"])) {
    $query ="SELECT * FROM stylecolor WHERE color_code = '" . $_POST["id"] . "'";       $results = mysqli_query($con,$query);
     while (($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results))) {
        $data->option[] = $row;

    }

}
      echo json_encode($data);
  ?>
```

It's not changing  the image on slider but when I call it somewhere else it is working fine.
I am using 2 functions on 1 dropdown item ,i.e. it changes the other dropdown options and an image .

Answer (score 1):

You should use `style_image` as id. Like:

```
<div  id="style_image" class="thumb-image" >
```

NOT:

```
<div  #style_image class="thumb-image" >
```

Comment: it was typo in my question , i am using <div  id="style_image" class="thumb-image" > like this , an i edited the question . sorry my bad

Comment: @umeraslam can you update the code? Seems alot of typos

Comment: And also post a sample `data` response of ajax.

Comment: I have edited the question,  kindly check also the response of ajax is {option: [,…]}
option
:
[,…]
0
:
{stylecolor_id: "11", style_id: "6", style_code: "pnt1", color_code: "pnt1blue", color_name: "BLUE",…}
1
:
{stylecolor_id: "12", style_id: "7", style_code: "pnt1", color_code: "pnt1blue", color_name: "BLUE",…} it also returning an image . and /images

Comment: So the dropdown is not updating? How about the images?

Comment: And can you update your post with the dropdown html?

Comment: dropdown updates perfectly , images also load but it is not showing on the slider as i shown above in html , but if I put image somewhere else it is showing .

Comment: What library are you using for the slider?

Comment: just using css bootstrap and javascript

Comment: There are still missing `</div>` on code man. Please check your code properly.

Comment: I think you are using `flexslider` on you slide. Can you confirm? If you are.. Use this to update the slides instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151481/clearing-and-adding-slides-reinitialising-flexslider

Comment: To update images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151481/clearing-and-adding-slides-reinitialising-flexslider